# Need a .ps1 command to run at user login via GPO

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, powershell, group-policy, xml

How do I get the following command to run at user login (users don't have local admin privileges) via GPO (or some other way) to add VPN connection

```
Add-VpnConnection -Name "VPN" -ServerAddress "vpn.randomdomain.com" -TunnelType L2TP -L2tpPsk "SuperSecurePassword" -Force -AuthenticationMethod MSChapv2 -UseWinlogonCredential -SplitTunneling $True -EncryptionLevel "Optional"
```

I tried following this guide:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee431705(v=ws.10).aspx

But the sample script and .xml file link referenced resolves to 404 page not found (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=160558)

Comment: Did you sign your script?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your GPO's Group Policy Preferences, create a scheduled task that triggers at logon running with system perms.

Follow the [Weekend Scripter: Use the Windows Task Scheduler to Run a Windows PowerShell Script](http://Weekend%20Scripter:%20Use%20the%20Windows%20Task%20Scheduler%20to%20Run%20a%20Windows%20PowerShell%20Script) post but use the 'When I logon' trigger and set to use SYSTEM credentials.